# Vim Preview Window: show previous

Tags: vim, preview

Is there a way to show the previously shown text in the preview window?

For example, a preview of methodA is shown in the preview window and then methodB is shown replacing methodA, is there a command or a shortcut to show methodA again?

By the way, I'm using YouCompleteMe plugin which shows auto-completion candidates in the preview window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, doing the same thing that put the signature of `methodA` in the preview window.

Comment: Of course, I know doing the same thing would show methodA again. I'm looking for a command like :something or a shortcut - a key combination. I don't know if you're trying to help me or you're just showing your arrogance.

Comment: Both. The content of the preview window is generated on-the-fly by the completion script; that makes this window *and its content* completely transient. There's no "previous content" to speak of except, maybe, in the internal logic of the plugin that generated that content and opened that window. Now, if you use ctags or cscope you can very well press `<C-w>}` to show the signature of the tag under your cursor or `:ptag foo` to show the signature of foo but you'll most likely get a different result than with YCM. Note that, when used that way, you can go to the previous signature with `<C-o>`.

Answer (score 0):

`<C-o>` (from normal mode in the preview window) goes back in the jump list and should bring you back to `methodA`.

If `methodA` is in another buffer, `<C-o>` should work as well as `<C-^>`, which edits the *alternate file*.

Comment: It just bring back to the previous file where the cursor was and opened it in the preview window.